# Why is pandas not allowing me to create a new column for this dataframe and throwing a setting with copy warning?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a column in a dataframe using the following code:

```
df['engagement_clicks_event_subscribers'] = df['brands_publishers_lifetime_clicks'] / df['brands_publishers_lifetime_events'] / df['content_subscriber_count']
```

For some reason, this simply does NOT run. It throws a SettingwithCopy warning, and no new column is created.

The most confusing part to me is that it does run on a simpler mock dataframe that I just took from the pandas documentation, with no warnings:  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/05_add_columns.html

The only thing I can think of here is that there is a dtype issue causing a copy to be created instead of a view.

These columns are int64:

```
df['brands_publishers_lifetime_clicks']

df['brands_publishers_lifetime_events']
```

This one is float64:

```
 df['content_subscriber_count']
```

There are no NaN or null values.

Any tips here would be appreciated, it's driving me fairly nuts.

Edit to include the full traceback set of warning I get from running this line:

```
/Users/sangbinlee/PycharmProjects/pr-seismic/data_shaping.py:41: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['engagement_clicks_event_subscribers'] = df['brands_publishers_lifetime_clicks']/ df['brands_publishers_lifetime_events'] / df['content_subscriber_count']
```

I've also tried, per the documentation in the warning:

```
df.loc[:,'engagement_clicks_event_subscribers'] = df['brands_publishers_lifetime_clicks']/ df['brands_publishers_lifetime_events'] / df['content_subscriber_count']
```

This generated 3 times as many settingwithcopy warnings and also doesn't work.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback message to your question.  There is not anything wrong with the statement you posted.  If in fact you meant to divide one column by another column and then divide the result by the third column, that's what that statement will do.  It is likely the warning relates to something else in your code.

Comment: look at this documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html and try: df.loc[:, 'engagement_clicks_event_subscribers'] = df['brands_publishers_lifetime_clicks'] / df['brands_publishers_lifetime_events'] / df['content_subscriber_count']

Comment: Also, if you are making changes to df in anyway prior to this, you may want to may a copy like df1 = df.copy() and then try your code on df1

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Purely a Pycharm issue.

I'm using the Pycharm debugger and for some reason, the dataframe doesn't update in the "Variables" window of the debugger.

When I Data View to view it as a dataframe, I can see the columns – I imagine it would work the same way if I were to do .head().

Seems like a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22369